# ¿Es correcto mencionar la palabra "imprimido" en una frase?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, vocabulario

Está bien visto decir:

"¿He ***imprimido*** los documentos faltantes?"

Suena bastante fuera de foco la palabra.